# Divide by Zero: Infinite, NaN, or Zero Division Error?

Tags: math, programming-languages, divide-by-zero

Why isn't `1/0 == Inf` in every language? Is that not the most mathematically correct response?

All the languages I'm familiar with are capable of expressing both Infinite and NaN values, so why would they choose to throw an error or return NaN instead? Is it just to make life harder for scientific application developers? ;-)

**Update:** We should maybe close this question because I incorrectly thought that `1f/0f == Float.NaN` in Java. But I was wrong: it *does* correctly return `Float.Infinity`. That was my main confusion; the fact that some languages throw errors instead is understandable, so long as no language returns NaN.

Comment: 1/0 always returns Infinite, and possibly raises a floating point exception. 0/0 returns NaN, and possibly raises a floating point exception.

Comment: @Tim Nordenfur: see IEEE 754 §7.1 and §7.2 (dividend finite nonzero number and divisor zero → Division by Zero Trap or correctly signed INFINITY; 0/0 → Invalid Operation Trap or Quiet NaN).

Comment: 1/0 == Infinity is a classic mathematical trolling question. I bit and made an answer but really this question is just going to cause trouble.

Comment: @Steven But this is not a mathematics site, most programming languages actually *do* handle it like this and, your mathematical rigour notwithstanding, your accusation of trolling consequently isn’t very constructive. Without your insistence on this factoid your answer would be a lot better.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apart from the fact that 1 / 0 == inf is mathematically highly questionable, the simple reason why it doesn’t work in most programming languages is that `1 / 0` performs an *integer division* almost universally (exceptions exist).

The result is an integer, and there is simply no way of encoding “infinity” in an integer. There is for floating point numbers, which is why a floating-point division will actually yield an infinite value in most languages.

The same is true for NaN: while the IEEE floating point standard defines a bit pattern that represents a NaN value, integers don’t have such a value; thus such values simply cannot be represented as an integer.

Comment: This is the only answer that bothered to explain the difference b/w integers and floats.

Answer (score 4):

> Is that not the most mathematically correct response?

No, because in mathematics, division by zero is simply undefined and infinity is commonly not a value (or not a single value).

The reason that not all languages/libraries return NaN is that (a) zero-division is often the result of a programmer error, since it shouldn't occur at all in mathematically rigorous algorithms, and (b) processors might handle it by going into an exception state, so transforming to NaN would require handling such states, meaning division becomes even more expensive than it already is (compared to, say, summing).

Comment: Actually in non-standard analysis, division by zero is undefined.  Also there are a number of branches of mathematics that have definitions of infinity, often many infinities.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst the limit of `1 / n` will tend towards infinity as n approaches zero (from the positive direction) the reason that `1 / 0 <> Inf` is that 1 / 0 is  *undefined* (by mathematical definition!).

Comment: "the limit of 1 / n will tend towards infinity as n approaches zero" _from the positive direction_... If you approach from the negative direction `1 / n` approaches _negative infinity_

Answer (score 2):

Why the trolling? But I'll bite. This may vary on the way you build up your operators but the most conventional way to define division is just the functional inverse of multiplication. That is to say c = a/b is defined as c being the unique number such that c*b = a.

Now consider c = 1/0. Is there a unique c such that c*0 = 1? Certainly not within R or C. What if we introduce infinity? You could have a special case that says that 0*Infinity = 1. But then you break a bunch of nice properties of the multiplication operator. That is we would like 2*(0*Infinity) = 2*1 = 2. But we also want the associative property. So (2*0)*Infinity = 0*Infinity = 1.

In general a Field can not be extended to have a multiplicative inverse of 0 in anyway that preserves the properties you want.

That said, I assume you introduced the classic 1/0 = Infinity just to troll. Next question, how come languages don't recognize that 0.9 repeater does not equal 1.

Comment: ok, I'm overly rude here. But 1/0 = Infinity just gets me every time.

Comment: For the record, it wasn't trolling.

Answer (score 1):

How about `0/0` or `-1/0`? What if you made a mistake? It is not a good idea to signal the program zero division with an `Inf` result.

Comment: It's usually far better to signal that with, well, a signal. Just as the best way to signal that the program has trashed the stack or the heap with a signal. NOT some bogus value that propagates throughout. I almost always enable floating point exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

In a Java interactions pane, I see this.

```
Welcome to DrJava.  Working directory is /Users/morrison/Desktop/PhotoPuzzle
> int top = 1;
> int bottom = 0;
> top/bottom
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
> double topFloat = 1;
> double bottomFloat = 0;
> topFloat/bottomFloat
Infinity
>
```

Floating point numbers are inexact and can be very close to zero.  Making an integer zero is probably seen as a programmer goof.  These are likely the two distinct behaviors you see.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point operations can detect several exceptional conditions and react in a couple of different ways:

- Setting a status flag that can be later tested.
- Immediately generating a trap.

The first mode of operation allows high performance, while the second mode allows immediate notification of possibly erronous operations.

IEEE 754 defines some sane values for the result of operations that raise exceptions (e.g: dividend finite nonzero number and divisor zero → correctly signed INFINITY; 0/0 → Quiet NaN).

The IEEE 754 intention with traps, is that there would be user mode handlers that could inspect the operation, the operands (for Invalid Operation and Divide by Zero exception) or result (for Overflow, Underflow and Inexact exceptions) and exception flags and return a new user-defined result.

In reality, some languages don't even support accessing the exception status flags, let alone set trap handlers.

Even C provides very primitive support for trap handlers, C99 doesn't even define a portable way to set trapping mode, requiring e.g: passing some implementation-defined value to `fesetenv()`. Implementations will typically raise a SIGFPE, and the user will typically need to access CPU-dependent state to implement a IEEE-754-like trap handler.

Answer (score 0):

Because while `1 / 0` may at times be approximated as  `INF` or some other like value, it's not formally defined as such. On the same front is `10 / 0 < 20 / 0` ? or `0 / 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Division `a | b` by itself isn't defined for `b = 0`. Therefore implementations of this operation map this case to a special value, to express this concept.